# How make checkbox being true/false just after you checked them

Tags: javascript

I'm making a "What language you should learn"site but more complex
I don't know why but when i check my checkbox,they don't became true but when i reload the page now they are true

```
if (document.getElementById("langage1").checked) {
   html = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage2").checked) {
   phpmysql = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage3").checked) {
   js = true;
} 
if (document.getElementById("langage4").checked) {
   python = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage5").checked) {
   java = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage6").checked) {
   swift = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage7").checked) {
   batch = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage8").checked) {
   jquery = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage9").checked) {
   c = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage10").checked) {
   cplus = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage11").checked) {
   objectivec = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage12").checked) {
   cdiaise = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage13").checked) {
   construct = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage14").checked) {
   wordpress = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage15").checked) {
   unity = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage16").checked) {
   gamemaker = true;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage17").checked) {
   unreal = true;
}   
if (document.getElementById("langage1").checked === false) {
   html = false;
}
if (document.getElementById("langage2").checked === false) {
   phpmysql = false;
}
```

Here is an example of the commands that should make them true,any idea how to fix that?

Comment: your JS code will run when the page loads. By default, checkboxes are not checked. So, your last two if statement will run. If you change the value of a checkbox, it will not rerun your code unless you add some sort of event lister to the checkboxes. Also, if you check a value, and then reload the page, your checkboxes will become unchecked again, thus triggering the last 2 if statements again. It sounds like you want to look into using event listeners

Comment: Are the values stored - you mention that on reload the checkboxes are then checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add eventlisteners

```
document.getElementById("langage1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

// example function
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("langage1").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
```

This way you tell javascript to fire when you do something, in this chase a click. So every time you click the checkbox `myFunction()` fires

Comment: I'm gonna test that,thank you! ;) I never though of that